# Saving the output of a cell in jupyter notebook with a new line after each number

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I saved output of a cell as a txt file as follows:

First cell:

```
%%capture cap --no-stderr
print(q)
```

Second cell:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cap.stdout)
```

Below is a small piece of code that I wanted to save:

```
#%%
np.seterr(over='ignore')

a = np.uint32(1664525)
c = np.uint32(1013904223)
seed = np.uint32(1)

rng = LCG(seed, a, c)
q = [rng.next() for _ in range(0, 2500000)]
```

The file is saved, however the generated numbers are separated by a comma, but I want each generated number to be separated by a new line, not a comma

I tried to change "w" to "a" and add "\ n" as below but it does not work for me.

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Do you mean you want all elements from the list with each in a new line?

Comment: @tbone: since q is a list, for example [1,2,3], it is separated by comma. Try this, after q is generated `q = '\n'.join(q)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%%capture` capture all the out of the code beside it in this cell, so you can print out all the elements from the list.

```
%%capture cap --no-stderr
for i in q:
    print(i)
```

---

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cap.stdout)
```

`cap.stdout` handle what `%%capture` captured as a whole, so when you tried to add `\n`, it won't work.

Is it what you want?