# How to capture everything that is printed in a jupyter notebook based on ipython?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Inside a jupyter notebook based on ipython I have a function that prints something. I can not change this function as it is from a library. Let's take

```
def print_something():
    print("something")
```

as an example. When I run `print_something()` in a cell, I want to save whatever the cell is printing in a file. How do I do that? I tried `%save` and `%logstart`, but as `print` is not creating an output, they don't do what I want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112535/saving-the-output-of-a-cell-in-jupyter-notebook-with-a-new-line-after-each-numbe/57113015#57113015

Comment: Thank you! The answer to my question is already part of the other question. No idea what to do in this scenario, I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Here is a cell magic that captures Jupyter cell output: https://github.com/kolibril13/jupyter-capture-output. Import the package and then type `%%capture_text --path "cap/foo.txt"`. Furthermore, `%%capture_img` and `%%capture_video` is also possible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I have found the answer in another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112535/saving-the-output-of-a-cell-in-jupyter-notebook-with-a-new-line-after-each-numbe/57113015#57113015):

```
%%capture cap --no-stderr
print_something()

with open('/path/to/capture.txt') as f:
    f.write(cap.stdout)
```

Documentation: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture

Comment: what does `--no-stderr` mean?

Comment: @seralouk documentation link in the answer ;) 
options:
--no-stderr
Don’t capture stderr. (it ignores error)